Saving, Sending as email , Clearing, then, saving an excel workbook
What I am trying to do. By clicking a submit button I want to save the workbook, then send the workbook via email, then clear certain cells and save again. I am having trouble getting the code correct anyone have any advice? This is what i have so far
Sub ClearType()
Range("C4,J4").ClearContents
End Sub
Sub ClearDay()
Range("C5,J5").ClearContents
End Sub
Sub ClearDate()
Range("C6,J6").ClearContents
End Sub
Sub ClearTime()
Range("J7,J8").ClearContents
End Sub
Sub Submit()
 Dim xOutlookObj As Object
    Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xOutMail As Object
    Dim xMailBody As String
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
    xMailBody = "Please see attachment" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
    On Error Resume Next
    With xOutMail
            .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .Bcc ""
        .Subject = "order form test"
        .Body = xMailBody
        .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        .Send     'or use .Display
    End With
     On Error GoTo 0
    Set xOutMail = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
    
      MsgBox ("Your Request Has Been Submitted")
Range("D6:F6").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
End Sub


Please format the code so each step or command is on its own line.
